# host name resolution in dba_network_acls

Tags: oracle

When you create an ACL with:

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.APPEND_HOST_ACE
 (
 host => 'subdomain.acme.com',
 lower_port => 10000,
 upper_port => 65535,
 ace => xs$ace_type(privilege_list => xs$name_list('jdwp'),
 principal_name => 'myusername',
 principal_type => xs_acl.ptype_db)
 );
END;
/
```

and then a client tells Oracle to connect to a numeric ip address will Oracle use name resolution to match the host name with the ip address and if so, in which direction? Will Oracle try to make a reverse lookup for the ip address and compare the host names or will it make a domain name lookup and compare the ip addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The host in the ACL must match the host in the PL/SQL program attempting to make the connection. oracle will not resolve hostname to IP or vice versa when applying the ACL. – [pmdba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/203074/pmdba)